# PHP date and time format

Tags: php

I have the following table, I got all info correctly but the "date" appears in one block format:

```
<?php
   // search for desired team
   $searchQuery = $api->searchTeam(urlencode("Real Madrid"));
   // var_dump searchQuery and inspect for results
   $response = $api->getTeamById($searchQuery->teams[0]->id);
   $fixtures = $response->getFixtures('home')->fixtures;
?>

<tr>
    <td><?php echo $fixture->homeTeamName; ?></td>
    <td>-</td>
    <td><?php echo $fixture->awayTeamName; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fixture->result->goalsHomeTeam; ?></td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><?php echo $fixture->result->goalsAwayTeam; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $fixture->date; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Result:

```
Home Team           Away Team           Result        Date/Time
Real Madrid CF  -   RC Celta de Vigo    2   :   1     2016-08-27T18:15:00Z
```

how to add space between the date and time and remove the T and Z characters while I dont have access to php.ini file?

Comment: See [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and related [String Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the [`date()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), which offers many customization possibilities.

For the current case you might choose to write, for instance:

```
<td><?php echo date('m/d/Y h:i A', $fixture->date); ?></td>
```

Comment: Note `2016-08-27T18:15:00Z` is not a timestamp so you'll need to convert that.

Comment: @cFreed This looks good but I got strange date: 01/01/1970 04:33 AM

Comment: @chris85 I agree that _if it's not a timestamp_ it must be converted first. But whithout any information in the OP how do you know what it currently is?

Comment: Under the `Date/Time` column is the OPs format. See the `Result:`. @Isabella you need to use `strtotime` on the `date` first.

Comment: @Isabella According to the chris85 comment, we need to know _what_ is your `$fixture->date` (which type, how was it populated?)

Comment: @chris85 Oops, you're right and my bad, I didn't pay sufficient attention. So I'm ashamed somebody already upvoted my answer! You should post yours, to be accepted by Isabella.

Comment: @Isabella Sorry, chris85 is right. See his comment.

Comment: it is comming from API: https://github.com/dfrt82/phplib-football-data
Please check the question, I have edited it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `date` function with the `strtotime`. This will allow you to format your string as you want it. For example:

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime('2016-08-27T18:15:00Z'));
```

Note the `h` here is a 12 hour format. For 24 hour format use `G`.

Demo: https://eval.in/653840

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for the different date characters.

Alternatively you could use `str_replace` but that would just replace `t`s and `z`s.

```
echo str_replace(array('T', 'Z'), array(' ', ''), '2016-08-27T18:15:00Z');
```

Demo: https://eval.in/653838

Answer (score 1):

Your date is not a timestamp so you can use string manipulation to remove T and z by creating simply a function which you can use in future..

```
function replace_str($originastring,$valuetoreplace,$valueasreplacement)
{
  if(isset($originalstring)&&isset($valuetoreplace)&&isset($valueasreplacement))
   {
      if(is_array($valuetoreplace)&&is_array($valueasreplacement)&&($valutoreplace.length==$valueasreplacement.length))
       {
           for($i=0;$i<$valuetoreplace.length;$i++) 
             {
              $originalstring=str_replace($originalstring,$valueasreplacement[i]);
             }
       }
      else
        {
        $originalstring=str_replace($originalstring,$valueasreplacement[i]);
        }
       //any other stuff 
      return $str1;
   }
}
```

and in your code

```
<td><?php echo replace_str($fixture->date,array('T','S'),array('','')); ?></td>
```

note:avoid directly modifying the values of variables (i mean why the api might be adding that z and T in your date may be with some purpose so be sure to keep original values intact when you perform such replacements,just in case you need original value..:D)

Comment: Happy to help...also in case you need any additional modification you can do it in such one function...:D

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the answers of @cFreed, @chris85 and other contributors, I got it working this way:

```
echo str_replace(array('T', 'Z'), array(' ', ''), $fixture->date);
```

result:
**2016-08-27 18:15:00**